# Blob image not displaying even after 777 permission to cache (TCPDF)

Tags: yii, blob, tcpdf

This is the error that shows whenever I try to load the page:

```
TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get image: /var/www/html/example/protected/extensions/tcpdf/cache/img_d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

This is the line that causes the error (I think):

```
$pdf->Image('@',$logo);
```

img_d41d... isn't even in the cache folder. Please help. This is driving me insane.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$pdf->Image('@'.$logo)
```

(I'm assuming $logo is your blob.)  The blob data needs to be appended to the '@' sign in the first parameter rather than being sent as the second parameter.

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work. I've tried it plenty of times but it still doesn't display the blob image. I think it's in the TCPDF extension itself. I'm not sure, though.

Comment: How very odd, it works fine on my installation.  What version of TCPDF are you using btw? I'm on 5.9.206.